# Multiple select by location in arcgis using arcpy

Tags: arcpy, select-by-location

I wanted to know whether there is there any way of selecting features by using select by location multiple through arcpy, like "SelectLayerByLocation_management".

Comment: Of course, you can use `selection_type` as `ADD_TO_SELECTION` in the each run after the first run.

Comment: Iam having nearly 150 point layers and 180 line layers and 260 poly layers . all these layers are need to be checked by building layer. llike this i have more than 35 sets. so i was consfused to check all the layers and missing some layers also. i would like to request if any arc py script is available for this kind of selection please provide.it will be very helpfull for me.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to add extra details to it.  Comments are temporary and are not always read by potential answerers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gets a list of all layers and selects the features in them that intersect the building layer.  Skips the building layer so it doesn't select itself.

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
bldgLayer = "building layer" # Enter the name of your building layer here
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
for layer in layers:
    if layer.name != bldgLayer:
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(layer, "INTERSECT", bldgLayer)
```

Comment: these are some of the layers for Bus_Shelters, CellPhone_Tower, Community_Toilet, where to add these layers. if you can show me where these layers can be added. i'll do the rest.. Thanks to you lot..

Comment: @SudhakarP if you run this from your MXD, it will read all the layers from your MXD.  The line `layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)` gets a list of all the layers in your MXD.

Comment: iam getting the following error "Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SelectLayerByLocation_Management'"

Comment: ISSUE: <module> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SelectLayerByLocation_Management'" – Sudhakar P Jul 27 '16 at 9:11 FIX:
SelectLayerByLocation_Management should be SelectLayerByLocation_management